# Editor wants to change Full Article to Short Communication

Tags: publications, peer-review, publishers

I received a review from a journal (life sciences) for an invited manuscript. The reviewer has requested minor revision and edits. However, the editor of the journal requested me to change my paper from 'Full Article' to 'Short Communication', but I believe my paper doesn't fit for 'Short Communication' since I presented numerous findings. In addition, my paper exceeded the word limits (up to 50%) for short communication. Any advice on how should I respond?

Comment: Did the editor give any motivations? Or was it just "oh, btw, change the submission type"?

Comment: I see two options: 1. Do as the editor asks and shorten your manuscript. 2. Don't follow their request and publish elsewhere. I don't believe you have a chance of convincing the editor to accept the full manuscript (but stranger things have happened).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni No motivation at all. He/she just gave brief comments on how the method should look, while the reviewer only commented on a very little revision. That's why I feel weird about the Associate Editor's recommendation.

Comment: @Roland it was an invited manuscript, and I gave them the title and scope of the paper prior to my submission.

Comment: If the manuscript was invited, I would be much less amenable to such (late) changes. Could you add this to your post?

Comment: @Designerpot already did.

Answer (score 3):

Handle this the same way you handle any other dispute: you tell the editor you think the article should be a "Full Article" instead of "Short Communication", giving your reasons. If the editor agrees, problem solved. If editor doesn't agree, it's up to you how much you care how your paper is classified. If you really, really want it to be a full article, you can dig in your heels and withdraw the manuscript if the editor still doesn't agree.

I wouldn't worry about exceeding the word limit for short communications. After all, if the editor didn't ask you to shorten the manuscript, presumably he's going to break the rules in this instance.

Comment: Yes. I am considering this. The review was positive except for the editor's request. Thanks!